# How to restore my RAID5 after mistakenly failing one of the drives?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I have a RAID5 on Xubuntu 20.04, created with mdadm.  I failed one of the three drives by mistake.  The array is still working, but I get errors or responses I do not understand from my attempts to restore full operation.

SO: I wonder if I managed to fix it, and if not what I can do now...

I suspect the drive is still failed because of the "(F)" in the contents of /proc/mdstat:

```
root@camelot-b:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md3 : active raid5 sdf1[0](F) sdg1[3] sde1[4]
      7813771264 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [_UU]
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
root@camelot-b:~#
```

However, the output of --examine does not indicate a problem, and in fact the last line shows the array state as having all three drives active:

```
root@camelot-b:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sdf1
/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 07c3d55f:2c9b1534:6b0d5b78:dd9856ed
           Name : camelot-x:3
  Creation Time : Sun Apr  2 19:07:19 2017
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 7813771264 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 7813771264 (7451.79 GiB 8001.30 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 24275237:b493169e:9e88df0d:ebaae551

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Fri Feb 18 17:15:50 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : c9840d0f - correct
         Events : 26597

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Comment: Note that `--examine` shows array state _as stored on this specific disk_ (it's replicated across all disks),  so if you just marked the disk as failed, mdadm might have decided to avoid making any further writes to it. The command does not show the actual "live" state of the array, that's `mdadm -D /dev/md0`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the technical response, but it works… as I actually found myself in this same position. **This method only works if the machine is local and you have another local computer.**

**Remember, RAID5 has recovery for 1 drive failure. As in, it'll rebuild the array from the remaining drives... as long as another drive isn't problematic during the recovery process.

- Physically remove the drive from the failing system
- Format the failed drive, using a different machine
- Insert the newly formatted drive back into the original machine
- The RAID array should begin the recovery process and rebuild the failed drive
- You should be back up and running when recovery completes

I cannot advise making configuration changes that you’re unfamiliar with. If your data is unrecoverable, there’s no need to waste time rebuilding your array, fixing your health status.

Comment: The "put it back in" part was a bit vague.  What I wound up with is a spare.  I need to know how to tell mdadm to rebuild its contents and put it back in.  Actual commands, please, because the documentation and terminology is so sketchy.

Comment: My apologies! I updated my response.  I was trying to take the "Repair for Dummies" path, but I ended up being the dummy 

Answer (score 1):

If there has been few or no changes to the data on the array since you failed the disk you might be able to use --re-add
You can check the number of events on each drive:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sd[e-g]1 | egrep 'Event|/dev/sd'
```

If the number of events are not too far behind (and you have bitmap enabled) you can re-add:

```
mdadm /dev/md3 --re-add /dev/sdf1
```

If that doesn't work you will need to add the disk again (this might trigger a full rebuild)

```
mdadm /dev/md3 -a /dev/sdf1
```

According to the documentation, mdadm will try re-add first when issuing the add (-a, --add) command. Running re-add is useful if you want to try adding the drive without a resync and not have it fall back to resyncing right away if re-add doesn't' work.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I looked at mdadm -D and sdf1 was marked removed.  The events were withing 1% of eachother (+- 100 or so).  But a re-add just made it a spare, and the third position is empty.  How do I really get it in there?  Just adding it now fails because it is "busy".